There are $13$ points on the circumference of a circle with radius $13$. Prove that we can pick 3 of the points which form a triangle with area $<13$.

There are $13$ marked points on the circumference of a circle with radius $13$. Prove that we can choose three of the marked points which form a triangle with area less than $13$.

If you wanted to know, this is one of the questions from the NZMO.
I approached this problem in this way:
Divide the circle into $6$ equal $(60°)$ arcs. By the pigeon-hole principle (since
$13 > 2×6$) there exists at least one arc which contains at least three of the marked points.
Let this $60°$ arc be $AB$, and let the three marked points be $X, Y$ and $Z$ in that order.
Here is a picture: 
Let $M$ be the midpoint of arc $AB$. Points $X$ and $Z$ both lie within the minor arc $AB$ so
the base of triangle $XYZ$ is less than or equal to the base of triangle $AMB$. Also
the distance from $Y$ to $XZ$ is less than or equal to the distance from $Y$ to $AB$, which is
at most the distance from $M$ to $AB$. Hence: the base and height of triangle $XYZ$ are
less than or equal to the base and height of triangle $AMB$ respectively. Therefore
area$(XYZ)$ $≤$ area$(AMB)$. So it suffices to show that area$(AMB) < 13$.
I feel that I am pretty close to solving the problem but do not know how to end it. If somebody could solve this for me, I would appreciate it. Thank you very much.

@JyrkiLahtonen Its the NZMO 2020

The NZMO has no ongoing contests. This year Round 1 has ended:https://www.mathsolympiad.org.nz/news/?article=122/.

@JyrkiLahtonen, I see what you mean, I'll retry. Thank you very much.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@JyrkiLahtonen I get about 1.74 for the distance from $M$ to the line $AB$. Among other ways of calculating it, it's $\frac{13}{2}\tan(15^\circ)$.

@JyrkiLahtonen $AB=2\cdot13\sin(\pi/6)$

Oops. You're right @DavidK, I had not had enough coffee or something. That makes a difference to the OP's approach!

Hint: Let the points on the circle be, in clockwise order, $P_0$, $P_1$, $P_2$, $\ldots$, $P_{12}$.
Let's count their indices modulo $13$, so we also call $P_{13}=P_0$, $P_{14}=P_1$ etc. Let $O$ be the center of the circle, and let
$$\alpha_i=\angle P_iOP_{i+2}$$
be the angle corresponding to the arc from $P_i$ to $P_{i+2}$.

Why do we have $$\sum_{i=0}^{12}\alpha_i=4\pi?$$ $P_0\to P_2\to P_4\to\cdots\to P_{12}\to P_1\to P_3\to P_5\to\cdots\to P_{11}\to P_0.$
Why does this imply that there exists an index $j$, $0\le j\le12$, such that $\alpha_j\le 4\pi/13$.
What can you say when you repeat the exercise in your approach with $A=P_j$, $B=P_{j+2}$ instead?

